# How to run specific tests in all browsers using maven and testng?

Tags: java, maven, testng

I am using "testng" framework and "maven" to run my tests from command line.

I want to run tests in all browsers for which we need to configure testng.xml for all browsers(which I have done)

However I want to run specific tests in all browsers.Is there a way to achieve this?

I know for running specific tests in **single browser** we use maven commands like below:

```
mvn -Dtest=TestFile test
```

However it is not possible to specify both testng and -Dtest together
like:

```
mvn -DsuiteXmlFiles="mytestng.xml" -Dtest="MyTest" test
```

(Also, pom.xml cannot take multivalue parameters)
Please suggest something for this case

Comment: If you are already using TestNG why not using groups for such things ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of getting this done is to by an implementation of `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` within which you can get the value that was passed via `-Dtest` using `System.getProperty("test")` as the method to be executed. Now within the `transform()` method, you disable every other method apart from the one that was passed via `-Dtest`